# python asynchronous threads/process

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have to come up with some event simulation with three threads.

1. this thread generates "ticks" at regular intervals (it has no other functionality)
2. this thread generates "tasks" (an abstraction that i use to describe one set of functions). the task generation rate is guided by a distribution
3. this thread generates "workers" (who pick up the tasks generated by 2 and do some processing). workers generation rate is guided by a different distribution

at each tick, the threads 2 & 3 should check if they are awake, if they are, then processing is done, else, the processing starts at the end of their sleep time.

I have used some form of sleep in my code, but does not give the result exactly as i need.

at each tick, i do this:

```
def run(self):    
        while True:
            task = Task().create()
            self.numTasks += 1            
            task_wait_time = Random.poisson(<value read off a config>)
            time.sleep(task_wait_time)
            worker = Worker().create()
            self.numWorkers += 1
            worker_wait_time = Random.poisson(<different value read  off a config>)
```

but here, quite obviously, things are not right. the task wait and then worker wait.
there can be parallel wait happening, or parallel task and worker generation.

I did read about threading module, but haven't been able get all 3 things working using that. Following some examples online, i have come up with a thread version which does not use the "tick" but the other two. I am yet to test it though.

I am not clear how to make this work, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to link the task to the worker. 
To do that, you can use a queue, with its method put and get. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue

Or use an event object with its method set and wait. See:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects

The part missing here is the information exchange between the "scheduler" that create the task and the worker.